# Open a Rails 6 link_to in another tab

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to open a link in another tab

I have this

```
<%= link_to 'Home',  root_path if current_user %>
```

And I have tried this

```
<%= link_to 'Home',  root_path if current_user, target: :_blank %>
```

But nothing works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like below **(place the if condition in last )** :-

```
<%= link_to 'Home',  root_path, target: :_blank if current_user %>
```

**Signature:-**

```
link_to(body, url, html_options = {})
```

To open a link in another tab we have to use `target: :_blank` option of html.

For more see this reference :- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to